# Why does a session cookie appear to be HTTP-Only in Chrome but not IE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a site that stores a random session ID in a session cookie. In Chrome dev tools it looks like this...

[image: Chrome]

Notice it says the cookie is http only. But in IE I see it is not set to http-only...

[image: IE]

Notice this one is not HTTP-Only. Finally firefox has it as http-only too....

[image: firefox]

So do newer browsers just default to http-only for session cookies? Why is it Http-only on some browsers but not others?

Comment: well, the web application calling the browsers SET-COOKIE method will specify the attributes of the cookie, including rules like domain, secure, http-only, etc. without knowing that the site did (or didn't) do so, there isn't a good way to directly answer your query.

Comment: I can confirm that in no browser the http-only flag is returned. I see that in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247143/how-is-httponly-get-set-for-asp-net-sessionid-cookie it seems to suggest that ASP defaults to this value, however, I would still expect to see it in the response header as http-only if this is the case which I do not.

Comment: in prior versions of .Net framework documentation, its explicitly stated that the default value for HTTPOnly is false, but that has been removed from the documentation for newer versions of the .Net framework, so its unclear without experimentation. You could just run the site in a debugger and inspect the cookie-object server side immediately after instantiation if you really want to be sure what the baseline is.

Comment: you can also proxy through fiddler or charles or whatever, so you can inspect the cookie independently of the browser its being sent to. that will probably work.